# extract my.setting.whatever from another exe

Tags: vb.net, exe, data-extraction, my.settings

Ussing vb.net I extract an image from another exe using the following code.

My question is, is it also possible to extract a setting value from another exe using a simular method?

```
Try
Dim ExternalAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath & "/" & PluginPath)
Dim TargetPlugin As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.StartupPath & "/" & PluginPath)
Dim ExternalResourceManager As Resources.ResourceManager

ExternalResourceManager = New Resources.ResourceManager(TargetPlugin & ".resources", ExternalAssembly)

If ExternalResourceManager.GetObject("MyStringRefrenceName") = Nothing Then
.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("MyStringRefrenceName").testing 'or is it value?
```

Msgbox(MyStringRefrenceName)

```
End If

 Catch ex As Exception

Msgbox("failed")

End Try
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Okay ... what I have managed to see is that there are also String references however if I reference there name in the above code change getobject to getstring and obviously replace .image=  to somthing like msgbox(TheObjectName) I get a catch error?

Comment: Settings aren't resources.  Have you tried reading the MSDN documentation on settings?

Comment: yeah though in resorces there are also strings and I was hoping to access them?